# Zend2: how to add custom route type?

Tags: php, url-routing, zend-framework2

I have a class `\Foo\BarRoute` implementing the route interface (`\Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteInterface`).

How do I add `\Foo\BarRoute` as a `bar` route plugin and make it available in configuration (e.g. `'type' => 'bar'`)?

So far I got the following Module.php without any effect :(

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $routePluginManager = $e->getRouter()->getRoutePluginManager();
    $routePluginManager->setInvokableClass('bar', '\Foo\BarRoute');
}
```

Can this be done via the module configuration file only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set the FQCN of your custom route class in the module.config.php directly?
in case you just need to use it in your module config file.

e.g.

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(

            'home' => array(
                'type'    => 'Foo\BarRoute',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(),
            ),),
    ),),

    ...

);
```

Comment: It's probably the way to go indeed (as it works) However it would be nice to be able to inject custom "short names"... like Zend does itself :')